# Como mudar a imagem pelo codigo behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Quero mudar a imagem pelo código behind, mas o caminho está errado.

Como descubro o caminho?

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images;Assets/Images/ativo.png", UriKind.Relative));
img.Source = image;
```

**Obs:**

a imagem ta no caminho: `Assets/Images/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui!

segue o código correto:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets\Images\inativo.png", UriKind.Relative));
```